# Some user fields in Django model.py not appearing in the database after registration

Tags: python, django, database, model-view-controller, mysql-python

I have a model for user registration. Users can successfully register and login. However, after registration some of the fields in the user model remain blank. The only fields that has the user details are the username, email and password. Other fields remain blank in the database. What could be the reason behind this? Where am I getting it wrong?

```
forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (AuthenticationForm, PasswordResetForm, SetPasswordForm)
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (AuthenticationForm)
from .models import UserBase

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Username', 'id': 'login-username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'id': 'login-pwd',
        }
    ))


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user_name = forms.CharField(label='Enter Username', min_length=4, max_length=30, help_text='Required')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=150, help_text='Required', error_messages={'required': 'Please, provide your email address'})
    #email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
    company = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    license_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = UserBase
        fields = ('user_name', 'email',) 

    def clean_username(self):
        user_name = self.cleaned_data['user_name'].lower()
        r = UserBase.objects.filter(user_name=user_name)
        if r.count():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exists")
        return user_name

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
        return cd['password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if UserBase.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Please use another Email, that is already taken')
        return email

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_name'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Username'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'E-mail', 'name': 'email', 'id': 'id_email'})
        self.fields['company'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Institution/company/business name'})
        self.fields['license_number'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Enter your license number'})
        self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'State'})
        self.fields['address'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Address'})
        self.fields['postcode'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Postcode'})
        self.fields['phone_number'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Phone number'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'})
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin)
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ 
from django_countries.fields import CountryField


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)


        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')


        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, username, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email adresss'))
        email = self.normalze_email(email)
        user = self.mode(email=email, username=username, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class UserBase(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = CountryField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    #User status
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['email']
    USERNAME_FIELD = ['last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py

```
def account_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            user = registerForm.save(commit=False)
            user.email = registerForm.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(registerForm.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your Account'
            message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject=subject, message=message)
            return HttpResponse('registered succesfully and activation sent')
    else:
        registerForm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration/register.html', {'form': registerForm})
```

Template

```
                             <form class="account-form p-4 rounded col-lg-10 mx-auto" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <h3 class="mb-2 font-weight-bold">Create an account</h3>
                                <p class="mb-4">It's free and only takes a minute.</p>
                                <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                                    {{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|striptags }}
                                </div>

                                <label>{{ form.user_name.label }}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.user_name }}
                                <label>{{ form.email.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.email }}
                                <label>{{ form.company.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.company }}
                                <label>{{ form.license_number.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.license_number }}
                                <label>{{ form.state.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.state }}
                                <label>{{ form.city.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.city }}
                                <label>{{ form.address.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.address }}
                                <label>{{ form.postcode.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.postcode }}
                                <label>{{ form.phone_number.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.phone_number }}
                                <label>{{ form.password.label}}<span class="text-muted mb-4">
                                        </span></label>
                                 <small class="form-text text-muted mb-4 small">
                                    At least 8 characters and 1 digit
                                </small>
                                {{ form.password }}
                                <label>{{ form.password2.label}}<span class="text-muted small">
                                        (Required)</span></label>
                                {{ form.password2 }}
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2 mb-4 mt-5 fw500 w-100" type="submit">Register</button>
                                <p class="text-center">
                                    <a>Already have an account?</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
```

Comment: Can you add RegistrationForm?

Comment: @Guillaume please check the code, I've added the form

Comment: I don't see anything that looks wrong. Can you print your user attributes, e.g. `user.company`, to see if it holds any value before calling `user.save()`?